# Map AppService URL to Application Settings value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I need the URL of a site hosted in Azure in the code behind: in Startup.cs for external login reply URL. I would like to map somehow the AppService URL settings (see first image below) to Application Settings (second image below).

Is it possible?

The URL I need:

[image: AppService URL]

Mapped to AppSettings, in code:

[image: Application Settings]

Comment: Would n’t it be nice to add it directly? Then read the environment variables when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the app setting, cause an environment variable already exists. Check the [Website Environment Variables](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#website-environment-variables) , there are `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME` and `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME`(example:site.azurewebsites.net), so you could just use the way to get environment variable to get the value in the code.

You could go to kudu site check the environment variable.

Suppose this is what you want, hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.